# DLL not found by Windows Service EXE

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, dll, config

I have a .net 4.0 DLL (class library) which is used to execute some operations for a windows service I've created. The executable of the service references this DLL by adding a project reference to the project of the executable. I have also tried a binary reference but the result is the same: InstallUtil fails to install the Windows Service from the EXE since it's unable to locate the DLL.

The system I'm working on is not using GAC registration for locating DLLs. Rather, at post-build the DLL gets copied to a child directory of the one in which the service EXE is located named "lib", and that exe has a matching .config file in which "lib" is referenced using:

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

We have multiple .exes and .dlls working like that. The project properties and .config file definitions for all these DLLs and matching EXEs are identical for all we could see.
However, whereas for all others InstallUtil has no problem locating the DLL, here it fails. When I move the DLL to the same location as the EXE, however, all works fine.

The .config file we're discussing is successfully referred for other purposes.

If you have any specific questions please share and I'll answer.
We're clueless.

Comment: This is entirely expected, InstallUtil.exe doesn't have a similar .config file to help it find that DLL.  Putting dependent DLLs in a directory other than the one that the EXE is located in is a practice that starts with -10,000 points.  It pleases a programmer's need to organize but has no practical benefit whatsoever at runtime.  Rather the opposite, as you found out.

Comment: I can totally relate to what you mean and I agree; I raised this concern the first time I touched this code. However, right now this is given and what I am trying to figure out is how it DOES work for all the others, and with this I need your help.

Comment: Not to mention that whether it is a good or a bad practice, at least in the documentation the snippet I've provided from the .config file is meant to do just that, so precedents exist not only for our system.